# weblogic java parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, service, config

I have a web service which access 2 other web services. I need to deploy this web service but some how I need to change the urls from the others web wervices, later.
My question is, how can I do to pass parameters to a web service at any time. Maybe a config file, or something. In .net we have web.config, do we have this in java?

kind regards,
José Cruz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses property files for runtime configuration to allow for changes after deployment.  Basically it's a text file with a list of key value pairs that Java can read easily and put into a HashMap which can be accessed by the user.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/Props.html